# How to insert my own obj and key in a NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: ios, nsmutabledictionary

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Location : NSObject
{
    int x_;
    int y_;
}
@property(assign) int x;
@property(assign) int y;
@end


#import "Location.h"


@implementation Location

@synthesize x = x_;
@synthesize y = y_;
@end


-(id) calcKey:(int)x theY:(int)y{
    Location* loc = [[Location alloc]init];
    loc.x = x;
    loc.y = y;
    return loc;
} 

for(id innerObj in arr){
   NSMutableDictionary* dic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
   for(id innerObj in arr){
      MyStorage* storage = (MyStorage*)innerObj;
      id key = [self calcKey:storage.x theY:storage.y];
      [dic setObject:bri forKey:key];
   }
}
```

Hi, I am trying to add storage into a NSMutableDictionary, My purpose is to use this dictionary dic to accelerate further search where location (x,y) has storage.But it always failed... with the following warning, can any one help me ? Many thanks!:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Location copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b4b160'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using instances of your custom class `Location` as a key, and keys are copied when used in dictionaries, you will have to implement support for copying by implementing `copyWithZone:`.

The "zone" part of the method name refers to some old memory management scheme that isn't used any more, so you can just ignore that.

As asked in the comments, your `copyWithZone:` method should simply create a new object, set the instance variables and return the new instance. You might also want to override `isEqual:` and `hash`. More [here](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/HashingAndEquality).

Comment: then what should I do in copyWithZone?